# How to get column widths to align when headers are fixed?

Tags: html, css

I have an html table with 2 rows that are fixed at the top so they don't scroll along with the data.

[image]

First, here is the CSS that applies to the table:

```
#dataTable {
   table-layout: fixed;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   height: 100%;
}
#dataTable tbody {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
#dataTable thead tr {
   display: block;
}
#dataTable thead tr td input{
   width: 101px;
}
#dataTable thead {
   background: #bababa;
}
table thead {
   display: table-header-group;
}
table tbody {
   display: table-row-group;
}
td,
th {
   min-width: 38px;
   border: dashed 1px lightblue;
   padding: 0 !important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td:not(:first-of-type),
th:not(:first-of-type) {
   min-width: 105px;
   border: dashed 1px lightblue;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: #e7eff7;
}
/* Overrides */
table#dataTable.xLookup {
   table-layout: auto !important;
   width: auto !important;
}
table#dataTable.xLookup td {
   padding: 0 !important;
   border-bottom: none !important;
   padding-right: 0 !important;
}
table.xLookup tr.xActiveFilter td {
   vertical-align: middle;
   min-width: 105px;
}
table#dataTable.xLookup tr.xActiveFilter td > input {
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Next, here is the html table:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="xLookup" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="xSelBox">&nbsp;</th>
         <th id="col0" title="Sort on Option ID" sort="A" index="0" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer;">Option ID</th>
         <th id="col1" title="Sort on Description" sort="" index="1" style="cursor: pointer;">Description</th>
         <th id="col2" title="Sort on Quantity" sort="" index="2" style="width: 55px; cursor: pointer;">Quantity</th>
         <th id="col3" title="Sort on Material" sort="" index="3" style="cursor: pointer;">Material</th>
         ... lots more <th> ...
      </tr>
      <tr class="xActiveFilter">
         <th class="xFilterHdr">&nbsp;</th>
         <td><input type="text" id="f0"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="f1"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="f2"></td>
         <td><input type="text" id="f3"></td>
         ... lots more <td> ...
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="PickerTBODY" style="height: 469px;">
      <tr tabindex="0" tracked="false" class="">
         <td class="xSelBox"><input type="radio" name="chk0" optcount="0" id="c_000Q"></td>
         <td class="xPickerIDColumn" title="nj option #1">00_nj_option_1</td>
         <td>nj option #1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      ... lots more rows ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As long as my `min-width` is 125px or wider, everything is fine, but here is the problem: as soon as I get much narrower than that, header column text exceeds the width of the column beneath it, and the columns no longer line up. The further to the right you get on the columns, the more off-alignment they get. How can I force the header columns (both label and input) to always line up with the data cells beneath them?

1. How can I force columns to line up by truncating any text (or input control) (both in the headers and in the data cells) when they exceed desired column width? (notice I'm already setting `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but that doesn't seem to do anything)
2. Alternatively, how can I force columns to line up by wrapping any text (and truncating input control), both in the header, and in the column cell values?

Comment: table cells naturally size to the content's width. if you want to override that behaviour, the simplest way I know of is to place your cell contents into `div` (or other element) with an arbitrary class that regulates size, text positioning, etc.
example, `<th><div class='first_column'>First Column</div></th>`

Comment: can't you use `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-x: hidden`?!?!

Comment: Anthony, that didn't seem to make any change. Where exactly should I apply those?